# How do I get differences between two json objects using GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I used this code to compare two JSON object using Gson in Android:

```
String json1 = "{\"name\": \"ABC\", \"city\": \"XYZ\"}";
String json2 = "{\"city\": \"XYZ\", \"name\": \"ABC\"}";

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement t1 = parser.parse(json1);
JsonElement t2 = parser.parse(json2);

boolean match = t2.equals(t1);
```

Is there any way two get the *differences* between two objects using Gson in a JSON format?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you will have to write custom code to do that,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you deserialize the objects as a `Map<String, Object>`, you can with [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) also, you can use [`Maps.difference`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) to compare the two resulting maps.

Note that if you care about the *order* of the elements, `Json` doesn't preserve order on the fields of `Object`s, so this method won't show those comparisons.

Here's the way you do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String json1 = "{\"name\":\"ABC\", \"city\":\"XYZ\", \"state\":\"CA\"}";
  String json2 = "{\"city\":\"XYZ\", \"street\":\"123 anyplace\", \"name\":\"ABC\"}";

  Gson g = new Gson();
  Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
  Map<String, Object> firstMap = g.fromJson(json1, mapType);
  Map<String, Object> secondMap = g.fromJson(json2, mapType);
  System.out.println(Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap));
}
```

This program outputs:

```
not equal: only on left={state=CA}: only on right={street=123 anyplace}
```

Read more here about what information the resulting [`MapDifference`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html) object contains.

Comment: As Guava is a big library, if you are only using this from it, you can 'extract' the code to your project, so you don't overload the *Dalvik's 65K method limit* 

PS: Just keep the license header to tell it is a class/method from Guava Project

Comment: @JoaoEvangelista Guava is fine for Android. See this StackOverflow question: [Is it a good idea to use Google Guava library for Android development?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14978699/1768232)

Comment: OMG. All those blogs... Why I didn't find it early, anyways thanks for the link. Also found in this link a link to *Compatibility Docs* for Android [on Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Compatibility#Android) Which says about the use of ProGuard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you clarify what Maps is in: System.out.println(Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap));

Comment: It's a Guava class, that is a static method. See the link.

Comment: Doesn't this apply only when the Json Object has only primitives? It doesn't seem to work for more nested structures.

Comment: The implementation is order sensitive for arrays, so it's considering a difference for two arrays element order is different `1,2` and `2,1`
  String json1="{\"a\":[1,2]}";
  String json2="{\"a\":[2,1]}";
affectively, there is no difference between these two most of the time