# Compare 2 Random Json String and return the difference as map

Tags: java, json, jackson2

How Can i compare 2 random json strings and return the difference between them in java.

I want to see the difference even when the order of the json object is different.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323256/how-do-i-get-differences-between-two-json-objects-using-gson

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the Guava library to compute the difference between them
[Maps](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference-java.util.Map-java.util.Map-)